# How to convert string to float without changing bytes?

Tags: python, python-2.7

My data was encoded incorrectly when sent through Kafka and stored on S3.

It was inserted into Kafka as a decimal using a Debezium MySQL connector, which follows these rules:

[image: decimal typing rules]

The relevant part of the Avro schema that gets created looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "PRICE_SELLING",
  "type": [
    "null",
    {
      "type": "bytes",
      "scale": 2,
      "precision": 64,
      "connect.version": 1,
      "connect.parameters": {
        "scale": "2"
      },
      "connect.name": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Decimal",
      "logicalType": "decimal"
    }
  ],
  "default": null
}
```

The problem is that when I read the data out of the topic and wrote to S3, it ended up in S3 as a string of letters. It's my intuition that the bytes are correct but instead of being represented as a string it should just be represented as a float.

Examples:

- 'JiU8' should be 24999.00
- 'JiDw' should be 24988.00
- 'RxFc' should be 46575.00
- 'LyZQ' should be 30900.00

I've tried using struct and ord but can't seem to find the right combination to convert it back to the float form.

Here's some of my attempts:

```bash
>>> struct.unpack('f','JiU8');
(5.088121542939916e-05,)
>>> struct.unpack('>f','JiU8');
(3822926.0,)
```

I have an Apache Spark job (Python 2.7) reading from S3 and moving the data into an OLAP database, so I'm hoping I could fix the data issue in Python before inserting into the database.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code you wrote that used the `struct` module—seems like it would have worked.

Comment: Have you considered the decimal module? Its an alternative to floats that are exact.

Comment: The chances of these floats becoming these printable characters I would imagine are pretty low... so presumably the strings have been encoded in some fashion - any idea how they were encoded?

Comment: @martineau I've added some of my attempts.

Comment: @AChampion I think you're onto something...I posted the documentation of the tool I'm using to insert into Kafka.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like those strings represent data in the IEEE 754 format `struct` expects, so your intuition may be wrong. If not, then your only hope is to figure-out how the original float values were converted to the string of byte values you now have—something like what @AChampion said  about determining the encoding used.

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. While I don't know exactly how the data was being encoded, I was able to find a solution.

My pipeline is Kafka ->(Sink Connector)-> S3 ->(Apache Spark in Python)->OLAP database. 

Your feedback showed me to shift my focus to fixing the problem further up the pipeline in the sink connector, where I was able to cast a Java BigDecimal into a float. The data is coming through perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the connector's *decimal.handling.mode* to *string* (see [here](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/#decimal-values)) which may help you to make the values easier to be consumed on the sink side.